# Anaconda-navigator: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, anaconda

Trying to start Anaconda navigator in Linux. Getting this error:

`byte indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution

This is what to do:

run: `$ source activate root` and then

`$ anaconda-navigator`

Answer (score 2):

Based on Chad Fulton's answer on June 24th, 2016 in [issue 748](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/748), I made the following changes. Anaconda navigator was able to run from the launcher.

Cut the line added to ~/.bashrc that was added by the anaconda install for path.

Update the ~/.profile path with the following at the bottom:

```
    export PATH="$PATH:/home/<your_username_here>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you'll have to logout and login.

This should fix that issue. The Jupyter notebook appears to work too, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

Comment: Just adding `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` to ~/.bashrc worked for me. I didn't need to logout and login though.